# TFS 2008: Team Project created with no Project Portal in SharePoint (WSS3) - How to create one?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Whilst I was on holiday, another member of staff, created a new Project in TFS2008. For some reason (I suspect they didn't have correct rights etc) when doing this a site wasn't created on Windows Sharepoint Services 3 so there is no Project Portal.

I need to resolve this so the team can use Sharepoint etc.

Initially, as the project hasn't checked anything in yet, I thought I'd just delete the bad project and create a new one with WSS setup.

Running the TFSDeleteProject command in command-prompt gives me an error:

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access <tfs-server-name>
```

Having looked into this problem, I think it might be because there is no Project Portal so it can't access it.

How can I solve this problem? I'd like to either create the project portal manually (I need steps as I'm pretty sure its not just by clicking a create button), OR a solution to allow me to delete and re-create the Team Project.

I am an Admin in ALL areas (I have triple checked!).

Thanks
Neil

Comment: I just created a new site (with portal) and tried deleting this one - worked successfully, so I guess I was right that because there was no portal, I can't delete the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the page for the TFSDeleteProject command on MSDN, it has a comment that links to a blog post where the guy has worked through what seems like the same problem. Apparently you need some specific SharePoint permissions to get this to work:

"add your account to the site collection administrators for the SharePoint project portal"

From the blog:

Ever try to delete a team project and get the above message? Are you in the Team Foundation Administrators group and scratching your head? I thought TFS admins could do everything! So I finally decided to get a clear understanding of the root cause of this problem.

The resolution is simple: add your account to the site collection administrators for the SharePoint project portal (described here). You can also do this as a Farm Administrator under the Application Management section in Central Administration. Hopefully, as a TFS admin, you've been added to the Farm Administrators group in SharePoint. The nice thing about the Farm Admins group is that it supports AD groups. The site collection administrators, however, does not. From Central Administration, you can specify a primary and secondary site collection administrator. Within the settings for the project portal site, you specify additional users, but you cannot specify groups.

Why can't Farm Administrators admin site collections by default? That's just the way it is. TechNet has a great article describing how SharePoint security works. The key content is as follows:

"Members of the Farm Administrators group have no administrative access to individual sites or their content by default. However, they can take control of a specific site collection to view any content. For example, if a site collection administrator leaves the organization and a new administrator must be added, farm administrators can add themselves as site collection administrators, which action is recorded in the audit logs."

So there it is. In short, the MSDN entry on TFSDeleteProject should include a prerequisite step to make sure you have site collection administrator permissions before running the command.

blog article: http://vsts-fu.blogspot.com/2008/10/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to.html

Comment: I actually sovled my problem before reading your post, but it was the same solution. I couldn't see the portal site so believed it to be that one hadn't been created. Instead one existed, but I didn't have access. Logging in as the install account allowed me to grant access and solve my real problem another way. Thanks for reply!